# Combination word problem

Tags: combinations

There is a group of people, 30 women and 33 men (total 63). A group must be randomly formed of 3 women and 2 men. How many combinations are possible?

My logic so far: combination (not permutation), order unimportant and repetition unallowed:

```
(30   (33
--- * --- = 4060 * 528 = 2143680 possible combinations
 3)    2)
```

I'm not sure about the repetition, should it be allowed? It would change the result.

Comment: [This page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) will teach you how to type in MathJax and $\LaTeX$ on this site so you can write things like $\binom{30}{3}$ without having to rely (*poorly*) on using ascii to do so.

Comment: The calculation is valid.

Comment: With repetition I mean that the formula would become (r+n-1)!/r!(n-1)! as opposed to n!/r!(n-r)!

Comment: We clearly have no repetition here. Every person can be chosen only once. At least, this would be my interpretation of the text.

Comment: @user395040 but would the "*outcome*"  (Alice, Alice, Alice, Bob, Charlie) count as "a group of 3 women and 2 men" (*where all three Alices refer to the same person*)... that sounds to me like a single woman and two men, not three women and two men...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pick three women ($_{30}C_3$) and two men ($_{33}C_2$).  The total number of groups is then the product of these two.

In this case, you don't have repetition, unless cloning is an option.  (But then you *really* run the risk of groupthink!)